# htaccess rule to parse php@parameter=anything as php file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, parsing

i want my server to treat `files.php@parameter=anything` as simple php file

i don't need to use symbol "**@**" as separator, such as "**?**"

but i still want to parse `files.php@parameter=anything` as a single php file without using parameters after @

i need something like:

```
AddHandler php-script .php@CNT=(.*)
```

but this doesn't work..

P.S. i got clother with code

```
<FilesMatch \.php@CNT=(.*)$> 
SetHandler php-script 
</FilesMatch>
```

but this doesn't work too..

Comment: Why so much trouble to replace `?` with `@`? If you're going to rewrite your URLs, make them something pretty like `/category/productID`

Comment: i have parsed website and it has thousands of files like "contenido.php@CNT=ARB0000778" - but they're not parsed as php..

Comment: so i can't rename them, cause these files are linked with others..

Comment: So fix the links? Should be relatively easy with a decent editor.

Comment: Please note that the `@` symbol has special meaning in a URL; you should avoid using it unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using mod_rewrite for this rewrite.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^@]+@(.+)$ /$1?$2 [L]
```

This will internally rewrite `/files.php@parameter=anything` to `/files.php?parameter=anything` and your URL will be handled like a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

ideal solution for me (BTW thanks for all who discussed topic)

```
<FilesMatch \.php@CNT=(.*)$> 
SetHandler php5-script 
</FilesMatch>
```